# GCM : running a xmpp server

Tags: java, android, eclipse, google-cloud-messaging

I m trying to run a demo on GCM(XMPP) that works bidirectional.
According to me it works in these 3 steps.

1 The client(Android-app) registers itself with the GCM server and get the registration id.

2 The client sends msg to GCM and then GCM sends it to the xmpp server along with the registration id.

3 - The xmpp server uses reg id to send msg to particular device.

Am i correct?
I have implemented the first step i.e, succesfully got the reg id on the emulator. I m running a xmpp server on eclipse on localhost (localhost:8080/GCM-App-server) but it is not receiving any reg id
My question is : `How can i tell GCM where my xmpp server is?`

Comment: You need to store your GCM id on some database, use your XMPP server to fetch that id and send message

Comment: but registration id is provided by the GCM to server , isnt it? I ll keep it in database, but who provides?

Comment: You are not clear, XMPP server is a different entity and GCM is different.

Comment: yes i do understand this.. My question is once the app gets the registration id .. how does xmpp knows about it ? thru gcm ryt?

Comment: no, create a webservice call to tell your XMPP server that this is your "GCM ID"

Comment: http://javapapers.com/android/google-cloud-messaging-gcm-ccs-with-xmpp/
Following this link , want to know about step 4?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65350/discussion-between-akash-and-murtaza-hussain).

Comment: javapapers.com/android/google-cloud-messaging-gcm-ccs-with-xmpp Following this link , want to know about step 4?
"PART B: The message sent in the previous step is relayed by the Google CCS server to the XMMP server application."

Comment: Did you created your demo? I also want to create this. here is my problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39924025/how-to-deploy-a-xmpp-server-on-a-host-to-work-with-android-clients