# How to deploy a XMPP server on a host to work with android clients?

Tags: android, android-studio, xmpp, openfire

I am trying to deploy a XMPP server on a remote host like example.com, and create a simple App in Android studio as a client, Several people will be able to install this Instant Messaging(IM) App on their android phone and start chat with each other over the internet.(Similar to Telegram)

What I have done:
I have installed Openfire on windows locally.
I found a [simple source code](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BxVa3_wqOp_rbGlRbVBYZjBNOEE) for android studio, and could configure it to work with Openfire locally. Right now I am sending and receiving messages in Genymotion simulator between users I have defined in Openfire.

Problem:
1- I want to deploy Openfire or any other XMPP server on my own host which my classmates can install my android App and able to talk with each other. Fortunately, couldn't find step by step solution.

2- For test purposes, is there a free Openfire web hosting site to deploy my own server and text my android client with it?

3- Or if you have any experience with [Xabber](https://www.xabber.com/), And [Conversations](https://github.com/siacs/Conversations) clients please comment here, I couldn't use Xabber, it is connecting and reconnecting, and couldn't figure out how to add friends in Conversations client to send messages.

Answer (score 3):

there are many free hosting sites available.. but it might be little slow
I have used these two,

- thefreecpanel.com
- byethost.com

but I think you cant install openfire on it, as it has setup that you need to run (.exe file), but this setup is only for first time

you will have to host them on a virtual machine on a cloud.. try azure for students, i think in student free account you can make a virtual machine.

I have checked conversations and it is too good. ChatSecure was also good but had too many issues.So, I have made my own xmpp functions and classes

Comment: Thanks, for your comment I'll check your solutions.

Comment: :).. thanks for the vote.. if you need the xmpp base class, I can send it by email, and you then setup the listeners accordingly